# Opera problems rendering Open Sans font

Tags: css, browser, fonts, opera, web-inspector

I've noticed navigating through web pages that some of them always render with this font.

[image: Example of font]

And it gets worst when it renders headlines or other texts.

[image: Image of a headline in a webside]

Inspecting the elements, it says that the font is Open Sans, but is not.

[image: Css capture]

And when I delete the font in css it renders by default.
[image: font deleted]
[image: default]
In my browser the default sans serif font is configured to be Open Sans. Which makes it weird because that's how it's suppose to appear, but instead shows a completely different font.
What's going on? Is there a solution?

Computed Tab screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

Maybe it's related to this?
[image]

Errors in Inspector
[image]

Comment: Please remember that if you want to show off what things look like, to use the actual [markdown](/markdown) syntax for that. Even just adding that leading exclamation point, `![description](https://...)`, is usually more than enough to turn a bad post into a useful post. Right now, your post just _links_ to the details, instead of showing them in the post itself.

Comment: I've tried, but because it's my first time using Stackoverflow, it says that I need at least 10 reputation to post images...

Comment: Note that what you're showing is just the CSS, not the actual computed/rendered style. In Chrome, click the "computed" tab rather than the "styles" tab for CSS, and in Firefox, click the "fonts" tab rather than "rules" tab for the CSS.

Comment: I've just checked the same page, the Computed tab, but at first look I don't see nothing weird.

Comment: doesn't matter: show what you see. If that tab says that the _actual_ font is open sans, that's a problem worth digging into (note that this still doesn't say which font is being used, you're showing the "computed value" string but not the applied font; scroll all the way down to where it lists the actual rendered font). If not, it should tell you what it's fallen back to. Also remember to turn on _everything_ in  your console. Not just debug/error, but also warnings, and not just for JS but also CSS etc. then reload the page.

Comment: Ok, I've been checking more and aparently says that the font rendering is pix PixelFJVerdana12pt.

Comment: Then it's almost certain that Open Sans is not getting loaded correctly (check the console for CSS warnings/errors) and the browser just picks "any random sans-serif font", as your CSS rules instruct it to. Since PixelFJVerdana is sans-serif, it has done what it was told to do: "open sans, or if that's not available, whatever font qualifies as sans-serif".

Comment: Sorry for the delay answering. I'm checking again the errors on the page, but I don't see where could be the problem. Also, I've opened other browsers to see if this happened, but in Firefox works fine. I post the errors above.

Comment: Yeah, so: the rendered font is "not the font that the CSS says should be used", which means that you're not loading the CSS necessary to load Open Sans, so: is this your website? If so, are you loading the correct `@font-face` or do you link to the correct google webfont (or other webfont service) link?

Comment: No, it's not my website. It's a random website form internet, but i've noticed that some websites have the same problem and I'm curious to know why that happens, why only in some browsers, and if I can do something to fix it.

Comment: The simple answer is "because there are _no rules_ as to which font should be used once the browser hits the general family class keywords". If website X loads font Y without using an `@font-face` declaration (either directly or by loading a webfont stylesheet from some third party service) and then tries to use it, the browser goes "that font does not exist. What's next in line?" and if the next in line family is one of the generic class keywords (serif, sans-serif, cursive. monospace, or fantasy) then the browser _entirely free to pick whatever_ - as long as the font fits the class.

Comment: (This is, in fact, a feature: seeing completely the wrong font is an immediate signal that there is missing font related CSS, and if these are not your own sites, you'll want to let them know. After verifying that you're not blocking webfonts due to script blocks, ad blockers, third party resource blocking extensions, etc)